# Conditions for a real matrix to have real eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The eigenvalues of a symmetric real matrix are all real. I was wondering if there are conditions either more general than symmetry or that may or may not overlap with symmetry to ensure eigenvalues to be real? Thanks!

[Motivation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_decomposition#Schur_decomposition):

> A real matrix admits a real Schur decomposition if and only if all of
>   its eigenvalues are real.

Comment: @Theo: Why is this linear algebra? Are matrices always associated with vector spaces? Can they connect to the outside of vector spaces? PS: I identify linear algebra with the theory of vector spaces.

Comment: Tim, sometimes you baffle me...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A **totally positive** matrix (meaning that all subdeterminants are positive) has positive and simple eigenvalues.

A **totally nonnegative** matrix (meaning that all subdeterminants are nonnegative) has nonnegative eigenvalues, but not necessary simple.

See [Sergey Fomin's minicourse](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~fomin/eidma.html) for links to more info.